# DocuSign listener xml response for voided envelopes, status is sent

Tags: docusignapi

The status for the voided envelope is "sent" in the XML POST response for the webhook listener. The document pdf bytes are also in the "sent" status . But the envelope is showing as "void" in the docusign account and the documents are voided too .@ Inbar Gazit

Answer (score 0):

You may need to open a case with [DocuSign Support](https://support.docusign.com/) and provide specifics such as your account ID and the envelope ID in question.

Are you using an account-level Connect configuration, or are you using an envelope-level EventNotifications definition? Either way, you'll want to confirm what events are set to fire. If you haven't enabled the 'Voided' event, it won't fire.

Are Logging and Require Acknowledgement enabled? If so, you can check the Failure queue to see if the event fired, but was rejected by your listener. Logging will show which events have fired, as well.

Finally, you can use a free service like https://webhookapp.com/ or http://webhook.site to confirm that the data coming from DocuSign matches what you're expecting.

Comment: Thank you. I have opened a case with support.